# Sinatra upload streaming

Tags: ruby, sinatra, filestream

Is it possible to have a sinatra app route handling large files upload through a POST with body streaming like these:

```
uri  = URI('http://0.0.0.0:4567/files')
file = File.open("/path/to/1.iso")
req  = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)

req.content_type         = 'application/octet-stream'
req['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked'
req.body_stream          = file

Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end
```

This is for a web service, currently, I cannot see how to handle this and I was trying to issue this request to my actual route:

```
post '/file' do
   File.open('/path/to/downloaded.iso', 'ab') do |file|
     file << request.body.read
   end
end
```

But it obviously fail with:

```
 `!! Unexpected error while processing request: closed stream`
```

Also cant get a not streaming version to work.

Would really appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
req['Transfer-Encoding']
```

does not force Net::HTTP to use chunked encoding for uploads, but only makes your sinatra think it is chunked. Please refer [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1112739) to implement chunked upload.

Excon is a nice HTTP Ruby client to implement chunked uploads after [this commit](https://github.com/geemus/excon/commit/5d343dd379a41e6352718ab40e865233a6663db2).